# Erlang: HTTP GET Parameters with Inets

Tags: http, erlang, inets

[This post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170208104504/http://userprimary.net:80/posts/2009/04/04/exploring-erlangs-http-client/) indicates how to make a simple `GET` HTTP request with Erlang's [Inets application](http://erlang.org/doc/man/inets.html#start-0).

Sometimes, URLs have GET parameters:

```
http://example.net/item?parameter1=12&parameter2=1431&parameter3=8765
```

Besides including the parameters in the URL itself, is there a way to create variables and then send them with the request?

Example appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```erlang
ssl:start(),
application:start(inets),
httpc:request(post,
   {"https://postman-echo.com/post",
     [],"text/plain","parameter1=12&parameter2=1431&parameter3=8765"},
   [], []).
```

You can use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503289/how-to-format-a-flat-string-with-integers-in-it-in-erlang) to use string interpolation to make a variable for `parameter1..parameter3=8765`.